# How do I output the results of this python variable under a button in html?

Tags: html, python-3.x

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CALOCATE</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="font-size:40px;">
            <td style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center ">CALOCATE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'"></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="two" value="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'"></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'"></td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <h2  style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center ">Click What You Require</h2>
    <input  style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center "type="button" onclick="alert('cals[0]')" value="SPEED"> 
    <input  style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center "type="button" onclick="alert('230.18444756937043 m/s')" value="SPEED">
    <input  style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center "type="button" onclick="alert('burnt -296.6710526315789)" value="FCALS BURNED"> 
    <input  style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center "type="button" onclick="alert(-307.97488038277515)" value="MALE CALORIES BURNED">
    <input  style="font-family:Century Gothic; text-align:center "type="button" onclick="alert('Your journey lasted 35 mins')" value="JOURNEY TIME"> 
    
    <table width="100%" border="0">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some variables in python that I want to be displayed as output when I click on the`buttons above. I've been trying to figure out a way to do this but I can't figure out a way to display this output without having to create a dynamic website. Is there anyone who knows how to change this? The code I want to get the variables from will be displayed below. I want the variables 'mCals, wCals, jtime and speed' to be displayed when the buttons 'MALE CALORIES BURNED', 'FCALS BURNED', 'JOURNEY' and 'SPEED' are clicked respectively.

```
class LocationsWebsite(object):
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.gzip()
def index(self):
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index-copy.html')
    template_values = {
        'locations': self.get_locations(), 'calories': self.get_distance()} #template_values is a dict. key is 'locations', values is a list of lists of two items (long, lat)
    return template.render(template_values) #make and serve the webpage

def get_locations(self):
    locations = []
    dates = self.get_dates()
    times = self.get_times()
    latitudes = self.get_latitudes()
    longitudes = self.get_longitudes()
    distance = self.get_distance()
```

## speed = self.speed1(dist, jtime)

## calories = get_calories(Age,Weight,Hr,jtime)

```
    for i in range(len(latitudes)):
        locations.append([latitudes[i],longitudes[i], dates [i], times[i]])  #make list of lists to enable jinja render as columns  
    return locations


def get_latitudes(self):
    latitudes = []
    with sql.connect(DB) as cur:
        results = cur.execute('''SELECT latitude FROM Location;''')
        for latitude, in results:
            latitudes.append(float(latitude))
    return latitudes

def get_longitudes(self):
    longitudes = []
    with sql.connect(DB) as cur:
        results = cur.execute('''SELECT longitude FROM Location;''')
        for longitude, in results:
            longitudes.append(float(longitude))
    return longitudes

def get_dates(self):
    dates = []
    with sql.connect(DB) as cur:
        results = cur.execute('''SELECT date FROM Location;''')
        for date, in results:
            dates.append(str(date))
    return dates    



def get_times(self):
    times = []
    with sql.connect(DB) as cur:
        results = cur.execute('''SELECT time FROM Location;''')
        for time, in results:
            times.append(time.split(":"))
    return (times)
    jtime = get_jtime(times)



def get_jtime(self):
    times = self.get_times();
    stimehr = int(times[0][0]) #this converts the first item(hours) in the first list(time) into an integer
    #so that it can be added to the second item (seconds)
    stimemin = int(times[0][1])
    stime = (stimehr*60) + stimemin
    etimehr = int(times[-1][0])
    etimemin = int (times[-1][1])
    etime = (etimehr*60) + etimemin
    etime = int(etime)
    jtime = etime - stime
   # print ('Your journey lasted', jtime,  'mins')
    return jtime


def speed1 (self, dist, jtime):
    speed = dist / jtime
    return (speed, "m/s")


def get_distance(self):
    latitudes = self.get_latitudes()
    longitudes = self.get_longitudes()
    slat = radians(latitudes[0])
    elat = radians( (latitudes[-1]))
    slon = radians( (longitudes[0]))
    elon = radians( (longitudes[-1])) 
    dist = float(6371.01 * (acos(sin(slat) * sin(elat)) + cos(slat)*cos(elat) * cos(slon - elon)))
    jtime = self.get_jtime()
    speed = self.speed1(dist, jtime)
    mCals = ((Age * 0.201)-(mweight * 0.09)+(jtime * 0.63)-(55.09))*(jtime/4.18)
    wCals = ((Age * 0.201)-(fweight * 0.09)+(jtime * 0.63)-(55.09))*(jtime/4.18)
    #print("If you are a female you have burnt",(wCals)," calories")
    #print("If you are a male you have burnt",(mCals)," calories")
    mCals = str(mCals)
    wCals = str(wCals)
    jtime = str(jtime)
    speed = str(speed)
    cals = [jtime,speed,mCals,wCals]
    return (cals)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could use something like [Pip - Python in PHP](https://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/) and simply copy the python script to your newly created php page. 
I don't believe you can do what you want purely in HTML + Python, you'll likely need a server-side language to bridge the two, such as PHP.</strike>

You can also just call a python file directly from PHP using `exec` .

As a third alternative, you could also store the data in a .txt file which both python and php/html can read and write to natively

**EDIT:**

create an empty .txt file in the same directory as your scripts.

Python to .txt :

```py
file = open("demofile.txt", "w")
file.write("now im writing a line in this file with and saving a variable ", var1)
```

From .txt to PHP:

```php
<?php
$myfile = fopen("demofile.txt", "r") or die("No file found!");
echo fread($myfile);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help but is it possible you can tell me how I would store the output of those variables into a text file which both can read? And how I would put it into the HTML code for it to be output

Comment: Sure, I've edited my reply :-)

Be aware you can run html in php, so simply rename your index.html to index.php and add the code above, should do the trick :-)